# Group Records and show on VF Page

Tags: visualforce

I am working on one scenario. I have an object called "Time__c"
Time__c has fields like "Role__c" , "Rate__c" "Hours__c", now my requirement is that I need to fetch all the records of time and show on VF Page but if Role__c is same and rate__c is same then I want those records to combine and have total of hours.

For example,
Record1 Role__c= Developer Rate__c=8 and Hours__c=8

Record2 Role__c=Admin Rate__c=6 and Hours__C=5

Record3 Role__c=Developer Rate__c=8 and Hours__c=7, then I should get only one record on VF Page for Developer role which should give 8+7=15hrs.

If Role names are same and are having different rates then I should show two developer roles on vf page
Can anyone help me out how to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

//This is Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page Controller="TimeTaskController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Time Details">
          <apex:pageblockSection >
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!timeList}" var="t">
                  <apex:column value="{!t.Role__c}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!t.Rate__c}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!t.Hour__c}"/>

              </apex:pageBlockTable>
          </apex:pageblockSection>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!timeMergeRecords}" value="Merge"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This is Controller.
public class TimeTaskController {
public List<Time__c> timeList{get;set;}
public List<Time__c> timeListAdmin;
public List<Time__c> timeListDeveloper;
Decimal adminHour;
Decimal devHour;
public TimeTaskController() {
    timeList = new List<Time__c>();
    timeListAdmin = new List<Time__c>();
    timeListDeveloper = new List<Time__c>();
}


public void timeMergeRecords(){
    adminHour=0;
    devHour=0;
    for(Integer i=0; i<=10 ; i++){
        timeListAdmin = [Select id , Name , Role__c , Hour__c From Time__c where Role__c='Admin' AND Rate__c=:i ];
        if(timeListAdmin.size()==1){
            timeList.add(new Time__c(Role__c='Admin', Rate__c =i , Hour__c=timeListAdmin[0].Hour__c ));
        }
        else if(timeListAdmin.size()>1){
            for(Time__c t : timeListAdmin){
                adminHour += t.hour__c;    
            }
            timeList.add(new Time__c(Role__c='Admin', Rate__c =i,Hour__c=adminHour ));
        }


        timeListDeveloper = [Select id , Name , Role__c , Hour__c From Time__c where Role__c='Developer' AND Rate__c=:i ];
        if(timeListDeveloper.size()==1){
            timeList.add(new Time__c(Role__c='Developer', Rate__c =i , Hour__c=timeListDeveloper[0].Hour__c ));
        }
        else if(timeListDeveloper.size()>1){
            for(Time__c t : timeListDeveloper){
                devHour += t.hour__c;    
            }
            timeList.add(new Time__c(Role__c='Developer', Rate__c =i,Hour__c=devHour ));  
        }   
    }
}
```

}
    // It's not best practice but i have done this task now you can also you map and done SOQl query without inside loop.

Comment: Hi @Venkata Sainath , I hope your problem will be solve , but it's not good approach to reach at the solution , and in this code is covering all conditions as you mentioned in your question, After this you can use to Map for best approach .Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Manish Mourya, Thanks a lot for quick reply and giving me the solution, I am new to Apex so just asked help. Regarding my question I just gave example of Admin and Developer but I can have multiple records with multiple Roles, if role name is matched and rate is matched then I want to group all those records and show on vf page with one record which should give sum of hours for matching roles and rates. Can you help me out in this if possible

Comment: Yes I understood your scenario , you just try above code , this will definitely work according your scenario. Thank You , If You got complete satisfaction about your problem then please tik this question as answered.

Comment: will it work for other roles, lets say if I have role like "Consultant"?bcoz in code we did not mentioned about consultant

Comment: But you mentioned  , role only Developer and Admin so this code works only two role , if you want to add role  consultant then , we have to write some code of line for it.

Comment: yeah thats what I am saying, I just gave admin and developer as an example to explain my scenario but I can "n" number of roles over here, so can you help me out on this issue, I can have multiple roles so I just want to group the records which have same role name and rate and add hours of those and show on vf page as a single record.

Comment: So in That case you have to make List of role. and add complete Roles in role's list and iterate role's List in loop , write dynamic SOQL for this role's list.

Comment: Can you please help me out Manish, I am very new to apex so can you?

Comment: Hello Manish, one more thing I need to mention over here is that Role__c is a Formula field, I am fetching the role from another object so its a formula field.

Comment: OK, which type of role you want to add in List Like 1 Admin 2 Developer 3 Consultant 4 Architect etc give complete name of role.

Comment: Business Development,
Consultant,
Senior Consultant,
Senior Technical Consultant,
Senior Technical Consultant 2,
Solution Architect,
Solution Architect 2,
AMS Manager,
Database Administrator,
Support – India,
Support – North America,
Developer – North America,
Developer – India,
Engagement Manager,
Project Coordinator,
Project Manager,
Technical Consultant – India,
Technical Consultant – NA,
Technical Consultant – North America 2,
Trainer,
Shared Services,
Admin,
Other

Comment: those are the roles I have for now

Comment: I have Date__c field on time, so on vf page I want to show two dates, start and end date when user selects dates and click on go button then I want to show time records between those two dates by merging the records which have same role and rate.below is the code I have tried

Comment: public class RolesFetch {
  public list<Time__c> projectrole { get; set; }
    public datetime startdate1;
    public datetime enddate1;
   public Time__c a { get; set; } 
    public RolesFetch(){
     projectrole=new list< Time__c>();
    a=new Time__c();
    }
    public PageReference Fetch() {
    startdate1=a.From_Date__c;
    enddate1=a.To_Date__c;
    projectrole=[select Role__c,SUM(Hourly_Rate__c),Date__c,SUM(Hours__c),SUM(Billable_Dollars__c) from Time__c GROUP BY Role__c,Date__c HAVING Date__c>=:startdate1.date() AND Date__c<=:enddate1.date() ];
    return null;
    }
}